# How do you make the fn keyboard button work like a Ctrl button?

Tags: keyboard

I'm used to having the <kbd>Control</kbd> button at the bottom left corner of the keyboard. It's a little annoying to be pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> when I wanted a <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the position of the <kbd>Control</kbd> button in the new Mac keyboard layout is just very uncomfortable for any finger to reach.

Does anybody know how you can make the <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> buttons change function like how you can change the modifier keys in System Preferences?

Comment: Does anyone know why on earth has Apple decided to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to map fn key only for combinations of alphanumeric keys? I would like fn key behave like control key only when pressed with combinations fn+a, fn+b..., fn+z, fn+1...fn+0. I would like still to get fn+F1, fn+F2... to work as factory default.

Comment: @Mahdi would like to know that as well. Worst part is their larger num pad keyboard has a big ctrl button and the fn key is somewhere else entirely. Consistency at its finest.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure which OS this started appearing in but in macOS 10.13, this can be customized in System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys:

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys]

Comment: I'm running 10.13.3 but do not see the fn Key in the modifier key window. Was it removed again?

Comment: @Spork I am also on 10.13.3 right now and I can still see the fn key modifiers.

Comment: That's peculiar. I double checked, but see only 4 options. It also doesn't show up on google images for 'modifier keys' (the only exception being the image in this answer). Are you sure it isn't something you've installed?

Comment: Sadly this only works to map fn to ctrl but it's impossible to map ctrl to fn.

Comment: do you know if this works for a laptop keyboard or just external one?

Comment: @William in my setup, it works for both.

Comment: I'm in 10.14.2 and also only seeing 4 options (fn not being one of them).

Comment: I can confirm the issue that others are mentioning in the comments (in Mojave, 10.14.2), strangely enough no key except the real fn key can be mapped to fn; you can map fn to command but not command to fn. I guess this is okay for me since I rarely use fn.

Comment: This, plus binding Caps Lock › Esc, is an absolute gamechanger for Vim

Comment: Apple doing it again, can remap fn to ctrl but not the otherway around, truly geniuses ahead of its time.

Comment: On my macbook pro keyboard (QWERTY)  I have **4 options**. On my iMac's external Apple keyboard with numpad (AZERTY) I have the above **5 options**. Both systems run macOS 10.15.5. Not sure if it's external vs laptop keyboard, or related to the keyboard layout/language. If it's the former, it would be kind of ironic, since on the external keyboard the Fn key is near the numpad and not located near the ctrl key.

Comment: On my MacBook Air I have 5 options including fn key,  but on my MacBook Pro with the same operating system Mac OS 10.15.7 I only have 4 options NOT including the fn key

Comment: I don't see the FN key on mine either in that option menu. (Macbook pro 2019). So ridiculous.

Answer (score 22):

1. Download and install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html)
2. Open Karabiner Elements and set the Target Device in the dropdown
3. Map fn to left_control and left_control to fn as below

   [image: Karabiner Elements Map fn to control]

Comment: karabiner is great and does all things

Comment: is apple a1243 or a1242 supported?

Comment: I'm on Catalina 10.15.7. This works for most of my uses but now when I press 'fn' (that should now behave like 'ctrl') the Touch Bar still reacts to that and in my set-up the function 'buttons' are replaced with multimedia ones. So I cannot press, say, 'fn'+'f12' because as soon as I press 'fn' 'f12' disappears. Any way to stop that?

Comment: @JohnnyBaloney: the same problem!

Answer (score 19):

This is my white whale.  I can't use Emacs without the control key being on the left hand side.  Recently I got a new MacBook so I had a chance to do this without Karabiner.

This is what worked for me to rebind the function key to control (for the built-in keyboard *only*), on macOS 10.15.6.

```
hidutil property --matching '{ "ProductID": 0x027e }' --set '{
  "UserKeyMapping": [
    {
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 30064771300,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 1095216660483
    },
    {
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 30064771296,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 280379760050179
    }
  ]
}'
```

Verify it with `hidutil property --matching '{ "ProductID": 0x027e }' --get "UserKeyMapping"`.

### How I found these keycodes

I've both seen the option to change the `Function (fn) Key` and *not* seen the option to change the `Function (fn) Key` on the same computer, using the same version of macOS.  Take it with a grain of salt, but I can consistently get the variant with the `Function (fn) Key` option to appear if I:

1. Have an [external keyboard](https://www.realforce.co.jp/en/products/87U_SE07T0/) attached, via a [USB-Type C hub](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMX12ZM/A/caldigit-ts3-plus-dock)
2. Open the `Keyboard → Keyboard → Modifier Keys`
3. Lock the screen using the external keyboard
4. Walk away for some time (wait until the computer sleeps)
5. Wake the computer by pressing a key on the external keyboard and use Touch ID to  log in
6. Now the Modifier Keys preference has the `Function (fn) Key` option.  While in this state, change the behaviour of the function key using the drop down list (I chose `^ Control`)
7. Copy `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.${__UUID__}.plist` (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907582)) somewhere else temporarily
8. Convert the binary PList to XML: `plutil -convert xml1 .GlobalPreferences.${__UUID__}.plist`

Contents of that file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-638-0</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
            <integer>30064771300</integer>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
            <integer>1095216660483</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
            <real>30064771296</real>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
            <integer>280379760050179</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[This page](http://www.neko.ne.jp/%7Efreewing/software/macos_keyboard_setting_terminal_commandline/) shows up if you search for these `HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc` and says that `1095216660483` is for the left function key, `280379760050179` is for the right.

I thought I was going crazy so I took some screenshots for proof:

### Modifier Keys preference pane without the  `Function (fn) Key` option

[image: Modifier Keys preference pane without the Function (fn) Key]

### Modifier Keys preference pane with the `Function (fn) Key` option

[image: Modifier Keys preference pane with the Function (fn) Key]

### About `ProductID`

You can find the Product ID associated with your keyboard using the `System Report` button: `Apple menu → System Report → Hardware → USB`.

If you use the `--matching` parameter to `hidutil` using a specific Product ID, the changes will affect that piece of hardware only.  For example, maybe you want to change the layout of the built-in keyboard, but not an external one.

[image]

Comment: Excellent post, thanks very much - this answer deserves to be much higher as it does exactly what is asked without the overhead of additional software.

Comment: Nice aswer! But it didn't work, unfortunately. `Fn` started to work as `Ctrl`, but kept also working as `Fn`, and `Ctrl` didn't work as `Fn`. I'm using the MacBook Pro 16 here, so it seems there is some hardwired stuff in this hardware, probably related to the touch bar.

Comment: I had the same problem as @BrunoJCM. This solution allowed me to map the Fn key to Ctrl, but it didn't map the Ctrl key to Fn. And when I press the Fn key, the function commands still pop up on the touch bar.

Comment: This is super nice solution ! Thank you! I value your process of finding out the right things. Now, if we need other codes, one can use https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app to find out the mapping (not my work).

Comment: @wheeler it seems some keyboards generate different codes for Fn. I've found out form here: https://github.com/amarsyla/hidutil-key-remapping-generator/issues/3

Comment: Is it possible only to allow fn+tab behave as control+tab? That would help me a lot, I don't need more mapping, just this one.

Answer (score 6):

you can use KeyRemap4MacBook

http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

you can find the included prepared settings list at this address:

http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html.en

as you can see there is the setting for <kbd>Fn</kbd> Key

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. And it has many other useful settings, too!

Comment: As a heads up, this has been replaced by [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I was happy, but then not as much.  I just bought a Logitech K850 keyboard.  Has a nice shape to help with wrist issues (for another time). Has keys from left as:

```
ctrl    fn    alt opt    cmd <butterfly>
```

Tried Karabiner but it didn't seem to work (tested by using ctrl-F in vi/vim).  Then I found this document [https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/features](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/features/#current-limitations) which lists a limitation.

> Karabiner-Elements cannot modify the fn key on non Apple keyboards such as Logitech keyboards.

Not for Logitech. Ouch.  Other suggestions?  Back to best buy again?  I'm really just looking for a mac layout keyboard with full size keys.  I don't care about the num pad, etc. on right side.  The K850 looked good except for this issue.  Some gentle ergonomics help is good.

Comment: I am still using the K850 after more than a year. Though I cannot swap the ctrl and fn keys, I am very happy with this keyboard.  I've grown accustomed to the layout and the feel is "oh so much" better than the macbook air 2018 laptop keyboard.  FYI.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a new Mac user so I don't know much about how this was solved before. But this seems to be fixed in MacOs Monterey 12.5 (MacBook Pro 16'' 2021). No third application required :)

[image: Keyboard preferences]

Answer (score 2):

You could also add this to [private.xml](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703210218/https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::FN, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::FN</autogen>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekezo/Karabiner/5df030be3a496f824379b7a942b9fd55cdd66507/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to trackpad gestures, [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) allows you to remap individual keyboard combinations. I use it to remap <kbd>fn ⇥</kbd> to <kbd>⌃ ⇥</kbd> and <kbd>fn ⇧ ⇥</kbd> to <kbd>⌃ ⇧ ⇥</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the one way to make Karabiner work with Logitech keyboards is to uninstall Logi Options, but then:

- the keyboard will behave like standard Apple keyboard - the mapping of function keys will differ from pictograms (I guess these can be remapped with Karabiner)
- you will need to find another way to configure mouse buttons 3-5.

Answer (score 0):

The [hidutil-key-remapping-generator](https://github.com/amarsyla/hidutil-key-remapping-generator) worked perfectly for me. You can access the tool online from [hidutil key remapping generator for MacOS](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/) and copy the configuration to

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.local.KeyRemapping.plist
```