# Change the functionality of the function and control keys on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I want switch the functionality of the function and control keys on the keyboard of the MacBook Pro.

There is a [similar question to this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88897/how-do-you-make-the-fn-keyboard-button-work-like-a-ctrl-button), but unfortunately the software mentioned, now called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), doesn't seem to work with macOS Sierra.

Is there a method to make this achievable in macOS Sierra?

Comment: [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) can change or disable the function keys.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere I believe they are only talking about the `ctrl` and `fn` keys in the bottom left of the keyboard, not the row along the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karabiner is being rewritten from scratch to support Sierra in the form of [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements). You should still be able to accomplish it with this "light" version.

Comment: Do I need to compile it or can I just download it from the "latest version" link in the readme?

Comment: @SkeletonBow The latest release is precompiled and can just be downloaded.

Comment: As a decade long linux user, Karabiner has been a life saver.