# External keyboard modifiers with Sierra stopped working (when typing non-modifier key on MacBook Pro Retina)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

When I upgraded to Sierra, my shift key on the external keyboard stopped working when I press a key on my MacBook Pro Retina's keyboard.
I have a setup where my left hand is using the external keyboard (to avoid pain due to chest compression), while my right hand is on the MacBook's keyboard.

Now when I press the left shift and a letter on the MacBook keyboard, the 
letter does not come capitalized. In El Capitan (and all other versions) this worked...

Any hints?

EDIT:

1. it's not just shift. It's command, alt, shift, control.
2. the modifier keys do work physically (when used with other keys on the same keyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the shift on that keyboard does not work anymore. In that case, you should use another button as the shift button. You could try, for example, remapping the caps lock button (or some other button if you want to keep its functionality) to the left shift button using [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (courtesy of [Tim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270771/197118) for showing me this!). This will enable you to press the caps lock button on the external keyboard to emulate the shift button's functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but Shift does work physically.

Comment: It might be a bit of a long shot, but could you try it anyway? *Perhaps* it might work. If you can confirm it doesn't, however, I'll remove this answer.

Comment: Actually I have command mapped to caps lock on both keyboards. But pressing command on the left keyboard and, for example O, on the macbook keyboard, does NOT invoke Command+O.

Comment: I just tried an external keyboard and pressing shift on it while pressing keys on my MacBook's keyboard seems to work just fine. Maybe it's just a problem with your keyboard? I'm running Sierra 10.12.3.

Comment: Thanks! That is some hope. What keyboard do you have? I too have Sierra 10.12.3. Mine is apple blueetooth keyboard (the one with AA batteries).

Comment: Same problem happens with a little USB wired keyboard (Genius Luxemate i202). Are you sure you can press e.g. shift on the external keyboard and e.g. F on the macbook keyboard and you get capita F? Or Command+O, etc.

Comment: Also pressing a modifier key on one external keyboard and a letter on the other external keyboard, does not produce the e.g. Cmd+O. That used to work in pre-Sierra as well! I'm very much used to one keyboard per hand, for ergonomy... And some modifier keys are best (or only) available on the left hand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56051/discussion-between-skeleton-bow-and-karoldepka).

Comment: [SOLUTION!] Ha!!! Now it started working.
Looks like Karabiner Elements kicked it the right way somehow.
Even though I did not exactly change anything relevant, just installed it and opened it.
Maybe the fact of installing /using karabiner forces sierra to use the old ways of handling modifier keys?
Big thanks for suggesting Karabiner Elements!

Comment: That's amazing! I'm glad your issue was solved.

Comment: Big thanks to @Skeleton Bow for the help in troubleshooting and for suggesting Karabiner Elements!

Answer (score 2):

[SOLUTION!] Ha!!! Now it started working. Replying to my own question (related to Skeleton Bow's answer/suggestion - thanks) : Looks like Karabiner Elements kicked it the right way somehow. Even though I did not exactly change anything relevant, just installed it and opened it. Maybe the fact of installing /using karabiner forces sierra to use the old ways of handling modifier keys? Big thanks to @Skeleton Bow for the help in troubleshooting and for suggesting Karabiner Elements!

Comment: Adding to it: now i've done my usual Caps-to-Command remapping in Karabiner-Elements itself, not in system preferences. Because the remapping in system preferences seemed to not work anymore now (gave up after few tries there and moved the remappings to Karabiner-Elements).