# What is the hex ID for Fn key

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I would like to remap my Left Control to Fn key using `hidutil`. This is the command I've been trying to use:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E0,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000??}]}'
```

There is a list of hex IDs on this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html
but Fn key is not there.

I couldn't find it in a USB specification either: https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf.

The ID (0x3F) found in this document:
https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data
is wrong.

What is the hex code for Fn key that I can use with `hidutil`? Or is it not possible what I've been trying to do?

(I would have remapped the keyboard using Karabiner-Elements if it wasn't buggy on my computer.)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the keycodes are:

```
left-fn:  1095216660483
right-fn: 280379760050179
```

Got it from [another Ask Different thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88897/how-do-you-make-the-fn-keyboard-button-work-like-a-ctrl-button).

I used that to remap `right-option` to `fn` via the terminal:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000E6,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":1095216660483}]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this from [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware)

Fn key down

```
Modifier Change
    Keys:       
    Key Code:   65535 / 0xffff
    Modifiers:  8388864 / 0x800100 ⓘ
```

`NX_SECONDARYFNMASK / kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn / NSFunctionKeyMask
        = 8388608 / 0x800000`

`NX_NONCOALSESCEDMASK / kCGEventFlagMaskNonCoalesced
        = 256 / 0x100`

Fn key up

```
Modifier Change
    Keys:       
    Key Code:   65535 / 0xffff
    Modifiers:  256 / 0x100 ⓘ
```

`NX_NONCOALSESCEDMASK / kCGEventFlagMaskNonCoalesced
    = 256 / 0x100`

tbh, it doesn't really mean a great deal to me, I'm no coder... ;)

Comment: I tried those codes but they don't work, or at least not with `hidutil`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Found this awesome app someone made which will generate the mapping command for you if you select the source and destinations keys from a dropdown: https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/

I was able to remap the fn key using the value 0xFF00000003.