# Hot to make the fn key work like Ctrl EXCEPT when using f keys (f1, f2, f3, f4)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

After looking it up I discover I can permanently change the behavior of the fn key - [How do you make the fn keyboard button work like a Ctrl button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88897/how-do-you-make-the-fn-keyboard-button-work-like-a-ctrl-button)

But I’d like this to be a conditional change. Specifically, I want the fn key on my macbook keyboard to behave exactly like control **except** for the fn keys that appear in the touchbar, I want it to still show the fn keys (f1, f2, f3, etc)

Is this possible on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this tool, perhaps it can solve your problem

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: I found no way to make Karabiner work this way, is only for simple remapping from one key to another not complex changes like the one mentioned (seems one can program complex ones but requires a lot of work https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html)

Comment: Remapping your brain might be easier than remapping the keyboard :)

Comment: I wish it was only from my brain, but Mac is so inferior in every possible way of customization that getting use to any of it just feels like a downgrade in productivity, like remapping my brain to learn to use Windows 3.1 when I was used to XP

Comment: I remember I had a productivity reduction when I moved from Windows to OSX, this is normal. I hope you can adjust in relatively a small amount of time. here are some resources:

Comment: https://aprendamosmac.wordpress.com/category/uncategorized/page/1/

https://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/mac-operating-systems/mac-os-x-finder-keyboard-shortcuts-3/

https://www.computerworld.com/article/3023544/28-keyboard-shortcuts-mac-users-need-to-know.html

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/20-apple-keyboard-shortcuts-business-users-need-to-know/

Comment: There are millions of little things that just can't be done in mac doesn't matter what you learn, like in Windows if you mouse hover the icon of "Explorer" you can see all the open windows of that App, in Mac is impossible to hover finder, you have to literally navigate every open window with the key shortcut until you find the one you need.

Comment: " millions of little things that just can't be done in mac " : the same thing can probably be said of all operating systems, don't feel discouraged by this, instead, I humbly suggest you try to focus on the positive aspects and elements of the platform. change isn't always easy. when I moved from Windows to Linux I felt less productive, however, I adapted. later, when I moved from Linux to OSX, I also lost some productivity, still, I adapted, therefore, if an old man who doesn't really like change like myself can see himself trhough the change of technology, I suggest you graciously let go of

Comment: the habits of the past, and kindly, with grace and patience, learn the new Operating System that was given to you by your employer. I remember back in the AS/400 Days, we had a guy who stuck on Windows98 long past it's expiry date, don't be that guy...

Comment: I have moved from Windows to Ubuntu, is nothing like this; the user-hostile UI in mac is pathological, like I can find a question on this site with 1000 points on why "Edit > Cut" is always disabled on Finder, turns out the "Cut" option there is for texts, but is not clear at all why is grayed out until you google it, the same thing happens with other thousands of little features where aestethics were preferred over usability