# are fn and control keys swappable?

Tags: keyboard

I am using bluetooth keyboard and I want to swap the fn and control keys.

Is it possible?

[image: switch control key to fn]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the built-in macOS modifier key options, fn can be remapped to another key, but no other key can be remapped to fn.

You can provide feedback to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is amazing keyboard customizer for macOS called [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements). I use in on my old Air to swap <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> buttons for at least five years. (In fact, I do some other changes too, like additional functionality for <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, but that's another story.)

See more here: [How do you make the fn keyboard button work like a Ctrl button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88897/how-do-you-make-the-fn-keyboard-button-work-like-a-ctrl-button)